# Borders around fields are not visible after page is printed

Tags: html, css

I have simple form with few fields which after user insert values can click on button Print and print the page.

Everything works fine except when the actual print is performing input fields borders are missing.

This is the form

```
    <form name="hongkiat" id="hongkiat-form" method="post" action="#">
        
    <div id="wrapping" class="clearfix">
        
        <section id="aligned">

            <div class="block">
                <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" class="txtinput">
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <label for="name">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" class="txtinput">
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <label for="name">Statement</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="" tabindex="5" class="txtblock"></textarea>
            </div>
        </section>

    </div>
    <section id="buttons">
        <input type="button" value="Print This Page" class="resetbtn" id="resetbtn" onClick="window.print()">
        <br style="clear:both;">
    </section>
    </form>
```

And this is the css

```
#hongkiat-form { box-sizing: border-box; }

#hongkiat-form .txtinput { 
    display: block;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #dedede;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 1.55em;
    padding: 11px 20px;
    width: 65%;
    color: #777;
        float: right;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset; 
    transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
}

#hongkiat-form .txtinput:focus { 
    color: #333;
    border-color: rgba(41, 92, 161, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(41, 92, 161, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(41, 92, 161, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(41, 92, 161, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none; 
}


#hongkiat-form textarea {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #dedede;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 11px 20px;
    width: 65%;
    height: 180px;
    color: #777;
        float: right;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset; 
    transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
}
#hongkiat-form textarea:focus {
    color: #333;
    border-color: rgba(41, 92, 161, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(40, 90, 160, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(40, 90, 160, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(40, 90, 160, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none; 
}

#hongkiat-form #aligned { 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    float: left; 
    width: 910px; 
    margin-right: 50px; 
}

#wrapping { width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
.block label {
    display: inline-block;
    width:150px; 
    float:left;
    font-family: "Droid Serif", Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 900;  
    margin: 5px;
}
label { clear: both; }
```

What I see on the printed document and scanned as pdf is this:
[image]

This is the demo of the form which looks fine..: https://jsfiddle.net/aooL87wy/1/

Comment: No.. I've tried to move the fields left/right/up/down also to check if by any chance they go one above other..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the box shadow effect for the print?

And here a simplfied border property :

```
border: 2px solid #dedede;
```

[Here a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aooL87wy/2/)